# relational algebra in query, want find the info I need but not sure I did right

Tags: sql, database, union, relational-algebra

```
EMPLOYEE (fmane, minit, lname, ssn, birthdate, address, sex, salary, superssn, dno); KEY: ssn
DEPARTMENT (dname, dnumber, mgrssn, mgrstartdate); KEY: dnumber.
PROJECT (pname, pnumber, plocation, dnum); KEY: pnumber.
WORKS_ON (essn, pno, hours); KEY: (essn, pno)
DEPENDENT (essn, dependent-name, sex, bdate, relationship); KEY: (essn, dependent-name)
```

I want use relational algebra to get the info below:

Give the last name of those female managers who work in each of the projects located in Miami.

Here is what my logic take me so far:

σ company ⋈ employee lname plocation = 'miami'

I'm really stuck

Comment: Be honest... Is this your homework?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't actually a programming question.. It's a relational algebra question.

Comment: @david hoelzer no it's for exam review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Department identifies managers. Inner join Employee and find only females.
Inner join to Works_On. Inner join to Project to get list of projects and filter on Miami.

Now for the all in Miami part. See if distinct count (per employee) of plocation from above matches count of all Miami plocations in Project.

I actually don't know how to express that in relational algebra although I know it's straightforward except for the last part.